# Room Database error during compilation of kotlin program

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room

I have this Model:

```
import androidx.room.ColumnInfo
import androidx.room.Entity
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey
import androidx.room.TypeConverter

@Entity(tableName = "ot_tracker_db")
data class OverTime(
    @PrimaryKey(autoGenerate = true)
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Id")
    var id: Int,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Title")
    var title: String,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "StartDateTime")
    var startDateTime: java.util.Date?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "EndDateTime")
    var endDateTime: java.util.Date?,
    @ColumnInfo(name = "Details")
    var details: String
)
```

and in my DAO

```
import androidx.room.*
import kotlinx.coroutines.flow.Flow
import net.androidtries.overtimetracker.Models.OverTime
import java.sql.Date
import java.util.*

@Dao
interface OtTrackerDAO {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.IGNORE)
    suspend fun insertOverTime(overTime: OverTime) : Long

    @Update
    suspend fun updateOverTime(overTime: OverTime) : Int

    @Delete
    suspend fun deleteOverTime(overTime: OverTime) : Int

    @Query("DELETE FROM ot_tracker_db")
    suspend fun deleteAllOverTimes() : Int

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ot_tracker_db")
    fun getAllOvertimes(): Flow<List<OverTime>>

    @Query("SELECT * FROM ot_tracker_db WHERE StartDateTime = :startDateTime")
    fun selectViaStartDateTime(startDateTime: Date): Flow<List<OverTime>>
}
```

And DB implementation as

```
@Database(entities = [OverTime::class], version = 1)
@TypeConverters(Converters::class)
abstract class OtTrackerDB : RoomDatabase() {
    abstract val otTrackerDAO: OtTrackerDAO

    companion object{
        @Volatile
        private var INSTANCE: OtTrackerDB? = null
        fun getInstance(context: Context): OtTrackerDB {
            synchronized(this) {
                var instance = INSTANCE
                if (instance == null) {
                    instance = Room.databaseBuilder(
                        context.applicationContext,
                        OtTrackerDB::class.java,
                        "ot_tracker_db"
                    ).build()
                }
                return instance
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I build it, it gives me an error of :

```
> Execution failed for task ':app:kaptDebugKotlin'.
> > A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.gradle.internal.KaptWithoutKotlincTask$KaptExecutionWorkAction
>    > java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException (no error message)
```

This is are the errors I guess:

```
> Task :app:kaptDebugKotlin FAILED
> D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:13:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Long> p1);
>                                                            ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:11:
> error: Not sure how to handle insert method's return type.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object insertOverTime(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:23:
> error: Not sure how to handle delete method's return type. Currently
> the supported return types are void, int or Int.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object deleteOverTime(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:25:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p1);
>                                                               ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:19:
> error: Type of the parameter must be a class annotated with @Entity or
> a collection/array of it.
>     kotlin.coroutines.Continuation<? super java.lang.Integer> p1);
>                                                               ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDAO.java:17:
> error: Not sure how to handle update method's return type. Currently
> the supported return types are void, int or Int.
>     public abstract java.lang.Object updateOverTime(@org.jetbrains.annotations.NotNull()
>                                      ^D:\TryOuts\OT_Tracker\app\build\tmp\kapt3\stubs\debug\net\androidtries\overtimetracker\db\OtTrackerDB.java:8:
> warning: Schema export directory is not provided to the annotation
> processor so we cannot export the schema. You can either provide
> `room.schemaLocation` annotation processor argument OR set
> exportSchema to false. public abstract class OtTrackerDB extends
> androidx.room.RoomDatabase {
>                 ^[WARN] Incremental annotation processing requested, but support is disabled because the following processors are not
> incremental: androidx.room.RoomProcessor (DYNAMIC).
```

Comment: what is the version of `Room` that you are using?

Comment: It's 2.2.6 Sir. Should I ise a lower version?

Comment: I was able to use `Room` with version `2.3.0` so lowering the version probably shouldn't be the fix for this :)

Comment: @mehulbisht  I actually did upgrade to version 2.3.0 along with some others to the latest version and it worked.

Comment: Nice to hear that :)